# Unexpected Bash glob completion uses first match even if ambiguous

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I have the following files in a directory:

```
$ ls
a-file-1
b-file-2
something-else
```

And I type

```
$ cat *file*<TAB>
```

The line unexpectedly updates to

```
$ cat a-file-1 |
```

(pipe denotes cursor) even though the glob also matches `b-file-2`. A bit stranger is if I start another shell, I instead get a match listing  on double-<kbd>TAB</kbd> (which I prefer):

```
$ cat *file*<TAB><TAB>
a-file-1  b-file-2
$ cat *file*|
```

**Q: How is this behavior configured?** I'd like to have the second behavior in the login shell.

It seems login shells are getting the first behavior, non-login shells are getting the second. However, my `~/.bash_profile` does little more than kick off `~/.bashrc`. (I don't have a `.profile`.) It seems somewhere somehow I must be changing the configuration.

The `shopt` differences are that only the login shell has `extglob on`, `hostcomplete off`, and `login_shell on` but changing these doesn't alter the above behavior. `set -o` output is the same. Tried `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` but that had no effect. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1.

**Update** regarding [comment by @mpy](https://superuser.com/questions/823257/unexpected-bash-glob-completion-uses-first-match-even-if-ambiguous#comment1082436_823257).

In a non-login shell, when I include a base directory in the glob and press Alt-G, the behavior is different than when I use <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>. It's this specific latter behavior I want to configure in the login shell.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>:

```
$ ls dir/*file*<Alt-G>
```

updates to

```
$ ls dir/|
```

removing the glob and not printing any matches. Whereas <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> outputs the matches

```
$ ls dir/*file*<TAB><TAB>
a-file-1  b-file-2
$ ls dir/*file*|
```

Comment: Please check if your key bindings are differing (`bind -P`). I can reproduce the behaviour of your login shell. But using `Alt-G` (`glob-complete-word`) instead of `TAB` (`complete`) I get the second behaviour.

Comment: @mpy thank you. Interesting but doesn't seem to be the cause. `bind -P` output from both shells are identical. Also, the behavior of `glob-complete-word` is a little different than what I'm seeing in the non-login shell with TAB-TAB. I've updated my answer to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, I get the horrible first-match expansion behaviour by default, but I think it's the fault of something in the programmable completion.

After a `shopt -u progcomp`, I get the nice list-expansions behaviour.

Your login vs non-login shell behaviour is probably due to getting `.bash_profile` and `/etc/profile`, or not.  (Or your login shell NOT getting `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `.bashrc`, if your profile doesn't source it/them.)

update: tracked down the bug in the programmable completion: turned on `set -x`, and looked at the output of all the commands that were run after hitting `TAB`.  Found where the glob expression turned into a list, and found that in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`

The problem was here:  (search for xspec to find these lines)

```
xspec=${1:+"!*.@($1|${1^^})"}
x=$( compgen -f -X "$xspec" -- "$quoted" ) &&
```

`"$quoted"` was missing quotes, so it was getting expanded there, in the completion-processing shell functions.  `$quoted` is used inside double quotes elsewhere in the script, so I'm pretty confident it's supposed to be quoted, and that was the right way to fix this.

reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1387057, will hopefully get fixed upstream and make its way into all distros soon.

Comment: Adding `shopt -u progcomp` to `.bashrc` seems to have done the trick. It's strange because `shopt` hadn't reported that differently between my environments. Great find with the quoted bug.

Comment: shopt -u progcomp disables programmable completion...  I was just saying that as a way to test if the behaviour was coming from programmable completion or not.

Comment: Ah, thanks. `bash` baffles me. So if I keep `progcomp` enabled, and add the quotes to `bash_completion`, I get neither the first-match expansion, *nor* the list-expansions behavior. When I hit TAB (once or twice), nothing happens. However, if I execute `bash`, I get the list expansion on double TAB (but `set -x` yields nothing there, strangely). Do you have any further pointers?

Comment: oh, hmm, I hadn't noticed that bash without programmable completion had pretty nice behaviour with glob expressions.  If you prefer that glob behaviour over progcom, then disable progcomp.  progcomp gives you stuff like being able to tab-complete man ab[TAB] => comp on commands, or  git c[TAB] => comp on git commands.  And esp. sudo ifc[TAB] => complete on commands.  Also stuff like find -[TAB] => complete on options.  Many commands have smart handlers to sometimes save you a look at the man page.

Comment: basically, there's 2 modes you can be in: programmable completion with all those shell functions loaded, or without that.  Choose by sourcing /etc/profile.d/bash_completion, or not, from your ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc.  (can also disable after already loaded, with shopt -u progcomp, or complete -r.)

Comment: Ah, so it's either progcomp or glob list expansion, but not possible to keep both? I also now see that without your xspec fix, when I start the second shell, progcomp wasn't working. At least now I have consistent behavior across login and secondary shells. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the unquoted "$quoted" that @peter-cordes mentioned, there's another bug in the _filedir() function:

```
--- /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion--OLD 2015-08-19 19:58:22.734667377 -0500
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion      2016-01-05 15:56:50.442988910 -0500
@@ -604,6 +604,8 @@
         # 2>/dev/null for direct invocation, e.g. in the _filedir unit test
         compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
         COMPREPLY+=( "${toks[@]}" )
+    else
+        compopt -o bashdefault 2>/dev/null
     fi
 } # _filedir()
```

This lets you eat your cake and have it, too: you can keep your "shopt -s progcmp" bash_completion *AND* if that doesn't find a match, it will fall back to using bash's default glob-handling.

Comment: This is great! I guess I just need to watch out for updates to the bash-completion package.